# How to use IF EXISTS in join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    LEDGER AS LED 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (IF EXISTS(SELECT ACCOUNTCODE FROM B_C_J_TRANS WHERE ACCOUNTCODE = '001809' AND COMPANYCODE='RAM' --AND ENTRYNO='25' 
    AND MODE='J') 
        SELECT COMPANYCODE, SUM(AMOUNT * 0) AS AMOUNT
        FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
        WHERE (COMPANYCODE = 'RAM') AND (MODE = 'J') 
        GROUP BY COMPANYCODE
    ELSE
        SELECT COMPANYCODE, SUM( CASE WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '800100' THEN BCJTRANS.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS AMOUNT
        FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
        WHERE (COMPANYCODE = 'RAM')  AND (MODE = 'J')
        GROUP BY COMPANYCODE) AS A ON LED.COMPANYCODE = A.COMPANYCODE 
                                   AND LED.BOOKCODE = A.BOOKCODE 
                                   AND LED.[TYPE] = A.MODE 
                                   AND LED.FINANCIALYEAR = A.ENTRYYEAR 
                                   AND LED.VOUCHERNO = A.ENTRYNO 
WHERE 
    LED.COMPANYCODE = 'RAM' 
    AND LED.ACCCODE = '800100' 
    AND LED.VOUCHERDATE >= '2015-04-01' 
    AND LED.VOUCHERDATE <= '2015-05-31'
```

This is my query i want to use if exist in left outer join of ledger table

Comment: `SUM(AMOUNT * 0)` looks strange

Comment: You don't have `BOOKCODE`, `MODE`, `ENTRYYEAR` and `ENTRYNO` columns in your `A` subquery but you use ones in the `JOIN` statement. It's impossible to rewrite your query without correcting this.

Comment: You are right i have added those field(BOOKCODE, MODE, ENTRYYEAR and ENTRYNO columns in A) and executed query provided by @VR46 query seems to work perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `Exists` to `Where` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   LEDGER AS LED
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COMPANYCODE,
                               Sum(AMOUNT * 0) AS AMOUNT
                        FROM   B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
                        WHERE  ( COMPANYCODE = 'RAM' )
                               AND ( MODE = 'J' )
                               AND EXISTS(SELECT ACCOUNTCODE
                                          FROM   B_C_J_TRANS
                                          WHERE  ACCOUNTCODE = '001809'
                                                 AND COMPANYCODE = 'RAM' --AND ENTRYNO='25' 
                                                 AND MODE = 'J')
                        GROUP  BY COMPANYCODE
                        UNION
                        SELECT COMPANYCODE,
                               Sum(CASE
                                     WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '800100' THEN BCJTRANS.AMOUNT
                                     ELSE 0
                                   END) AS AMOUNT
                        FROM   B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
                        WHERE  ( COMPANYCODE = 'RAM' )
                               AND ( MODE = 'J' )
                               AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT ACCOUNTCODE
                                              FROM   B_C_J_TRANS
                                              WHERE  ACCOUNTCODE = '001809'
                                                     AND COMPANYCODE = 'RAM' --AND ENTRYNO='25' 
                                                     AND MODE = 'J')
                        GROUP  BY COMPANYCODE)AS A
                    ON LED.COMPANYCODE = A.COMPANYCODE
                       AND LED.BOOKCODE = A.BOOKCODE
                       AND LED.[TYPE] = A.MODE
                       AND LED.FINANCIALYEAR = A.ENTRYYEAR
                       AND LED.VOUCHERNO = A.ENTRYNO
WHERE  LED.COMPANYCODE = 'RAM'
       AND LED.ACCCODE = '800100'
       AND LED.VOUCHERDATE >= '2015-04-01'
       AND LED.VOUCHERDATE <= '2015-05-31'
```

Am sure this code can be simplified if you share the original logic